# How to use onClick event on react Link component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am using the Link component from the reactjs router and I cannot get the onClickevent working. This is the code:

```
<Link to={this.props.myroute} onClick='hello()'>Here</Link>
```

Is this the way to do it or another way?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You are passing `hello()` as a string, also `hello()` means execute `hello` immediately.

try

```
onClick={hello}
```

Answer (score 61):

You should use this:

```
<Link to={this.props.myroute} onClick={hello}>Here</Link>
```

Or (if method `hello` lays at this class):

```
<Link to={this.props.myroute} onClick={this.hello}>Here</Link>
```

**Update:** For ES6 and latest if you want to bind some param with click method, you can use this:

```
    const someValue = 'some';  
....  
    <Link to={this.props.myroute} onClick={() => hello(someValue)}>Here</Link>
```

Comment: Or better `this.hello.bind(this)`

Comment: ^ You should actually always bind actions in the constructor as binding the way you have can lead to performance issues.

Comment: Link "to" is required, but often times I just need onClick(), currently, I have to do something like `<Link to="" onClick={this.delete}>Delete</Link>`. I wish "to" is optional here.

Comment: @newman Why would you use `Link` without `to`? If you don't need it, then just some other component such as a `<button>` with the `onClick` method and you're good to go ;).

Comment: I'm not entirely sold on React-Router nor Link either.  Sometimes it is there because of what the last developer did.  I'd prefer handling the reactivity up and down thru props for control over the workflow.

Comment: as @GuilhermeOderdenge mentioned it is better and more practical to use the **button tag**. **Use styling to make it display as link**. ie if you are using bootstrap you could go with `button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onClick={your_click_fn}>Link</button>`

Answer (score 37):

I don't believe this is a good pattern to use in general. Link will run your onClick event and then navigate to the route, so there will be a slight delay navigating to the new route. A better strategy is to navigate to the new route with the 'to' prop as you have done, and in the new component's componentDidMount() function you can fire your hello function or any other function. It will give you the same result, but with a much smoother transition between routes.

For context, I noticed this while updating my redux store with an onClick event on Link like you have here, and it caused a ~.3 second blank-white-screen delay before mounting the new route's component. There was no api call involved, so I was surprised the delay was so big. However, if you're just console logging 'hello' the delay might not be noticeable.

Comment: I have a callback url in my current component which I am saving in cookie in `onClick` before transitioning to new route. I wont get that callback url in next component so I need to do that before transition itself. Do you have any alternative to that? 
PS: The callback url should be accessible even after refresh so can save it in store.

Comment: If you're using react-navigation: I would say don't use Link, just use TouchableOpacity or TouchableWithoutFeedback, then in your onPress function you can navigate and pass your url as a nav param ```onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('NameOfNextScreen', {
              callbackUrl: 'http://.callbackUrl.com',
            });``` If you aren't using react-navigation I would just use Link's onClick and don't worry about the slight performance issue. It probably won't be noticeable.

Comment: Good advice! Thanks!

Comment: I think this could be perfectly fine, simpy handle the click passing the event and handle some logic  to see what you want to do and if you decide not to use the route change call ` event.preventDefault()`. I do get your point, but I had a use case where I needed to intercept the click and warn a user they where moving away from a route and if they were sure about that.

Comment: So would you say that you would use onClick on a Link if you need to do something else like erase a session or local storage token when you click on logout?

Comment: @Imriven I was just pointing out that there is a slight performance hit to consider if you use this pattern (slight delay navigating to new route). If that's not an issue for your use-case, go for it!

Personally I would just have a logout button rather than using a <Link /> and navigate programmatically in my onPress function using history. If you've set up authenticated routes, when you clear your token your app should redirect to the login screen automatically.

Answer (score 5):

```
 const onLinkClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ---do your stuff---
    history.push('/your-route');
};

<a href='/your-route' onClick={onLinkClick}> Navigate </a>
                   or
<Link to='/your-route' onClick={onLinkClick}> Navigate </Link>
```

Comment: @AdamHey You mean event delegation.  Apparently there's no noticeable performance benefits due to optimizations in React.  https://dev.to/thawsitt/should-i-use-event-delegation-in-react-nl0

Comment: Thanks for the link @manafire. I wasn't really thinking in performance terms, but more from a manageability perspective. if you can write a delegate that targets  all the desired elements then you don't need to add `onClick` on every element

Comment: Where's the history coming from?

Comment: @AdamHey Solution was more around understanding the concept. Also, there are pros and cons to each usage. handlers mostly give us the advantage to write custom logic

Comment: @verunar history would come from router hook or previously via withRouter HoC

```https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks```

Comment: @verunar `const history = useHistory();` which is imported from react-router-dom

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the function, in this case hello, you may **avoid writing event.preventDefault()**, otherwise the Link to won't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Link to use in react onClick event

   ```
   <a href="#" onClick={this.setActiveTab}>
     ...View Full List
   </a>

   setActiveTab = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(e.target);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

in ReactJs we have to use {} to use our Handlers use
onClick={ ()=> hello() } instead of onClick='hello()'

**Helper document** => https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html