# Add a onClick to React Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want my button to:

1. first trigger a *POST* request with its `onClick` callback
2. then navigate to another page using react-router facilities

I have proposals for each case.

This is how I can achieve the callback handling:

```js
<button onClick={handleSubmitfunc}>Submit</button>
```

This is how I see the navigation:

```js
<Link to='/secondpage' state={{from: variable}}>Submit</Link>
```

My code below tries to resume the two requierements, but doesn't achieve the goal. Only the callback is triggered but not the navigation:

```js
<Link 
 to="/secondpage"
 onClick={handleSubmitfunc}
 state={{from: email}}>
Clickable Link
</Link>
```

Does the combination fail because I have a state prop?

For reference, I've seen the issue before in: [How to use onClick event on react Link component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800815/how-to-use-onclick-event-on-react-link-component). That didn't help much.

Comment: you can create an onsubmit handler that gets activated onclick, does whatever you want. then you can push the url once you are done with the function. It depends on what version of react router you use, it can be history.push("yourUrl")

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your question. What is this `handleSubmitfunc` function doing when clicked? Where is this link locating in code? I suspect you are rendering a form and likely preventing *some* default behavior and breaking the link behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `useNavigate` hook for redirection.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...

const navigate = useNavigate()
...

...

const handleSubmitfunc = async () => {
  await /* API call here */


  navigate('<route here>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, I managed to get it working looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566405/react-router-dom-v6-usenavigate-passing-value-to-another-component/64566486